# Once again... libxmljs does not install on Win 10 with Node 15.5

Tags: node.js, xml, windows, installation, xsd

It appears that Xml validating with Node.js is not well supported on Windows. Installing libxmljs failed consistently with all 15.x Node.js versions on all my Windows 10 machines. Since my C++ knowledge is really out of date I'd like to get some assistance to get it run on my machines. Has anyone an idea? Are there similare problems with Linux or MacOS?

Here is the latest log produced so far:

```
    0 verbose cli [
    0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    0 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    0 verbose cli   'i',
    0 verbose cli   'libxmljs'
    0 verbose cli ]
    1 info using npm@7.0.10
    2 info using node@v15.5.0
    3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
    4 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 51ms
    5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 51ms
    6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
    7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
    8 timing config:load:file:C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
    9 timing config:load:project Completed in 6ms
    10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\XXX\.npmrc Completed in 3ms
    11 timing config:load:user Completed in 3ms
    12 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
    13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
    14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
    15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
    16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
    17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
    18 timing config:load Completed in 68ms
    19 verbose npm-session c0efbe9ef180745c
    20 timing npm:load Completed in 84ms
    21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
    22 timing idealTree:init Completed in 939ms
    23 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
    24 silly idealTree buildDeps
    25 silly fetch manifest libxmljs@*
    26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
    27 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/libxmljs 842ms (from cache)
    28 silly placeDep ROOT libxmljs@0.19.7 OK for: dxl-connection-manager@1.0.0 want: *
    29 silly fetch manifest bindings@~1.3.0
    30 silly fetch manifest node-pre-gyp@~0.11.0
    31 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings 47ms (from cache)
    32 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-pre-gyp 99ms (from cache)
    33 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 966ms
    34 silly placeDep node_modules/libxmljs bindings@1.3.1 OK for: libxmljs@0.19.7 want: ~1.3.0
    35 silly placeDep ROOT node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 OK for: libxmljs@0.19.7 want: ~0.11.0
    36 silly fetch manifest detect-libc@^1.0.2
    37 silly fetch manifest needle@^2.2.1
    38 silly fetch manifest nopt@^4.0.1
    39 silly fetch manifest npm-packlist@^1.1.6
    40 silly fetch manifest npmlog@^4.0.2
    41 silly fetch manifest rc@^1.2.7
    42 silly fetch manifest rimraf@^2.6.1
    43 silly fetch manifest tar@^4
    44 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/needle 64ms (from cache)
    45 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt 74ms (from cache)
    46 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-libc 142ms (from cache)
    47 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tar 144ms (from cache)
    48 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rc 160ms (from cache)
    49 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npmlog 164ms (from cache)
    50 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 161ms (from cache)
    51 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm-packlist 173ms (from cache)
    52 timing idealTree:node_modules/libxmljs Completed in 185ms
    53 silly placeDep ROOT detect-libc@1.0.3 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^1.0.2
    54 silly placeDep ROOT needle@2.5.2 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^2.2.1
    55 silly placeDep ROOT nopt@4.0.3 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^4.0.1
    56 silly placeDep ROOT npm-packlist@1.4.8 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^1.1.6
    57 silly placeDep ROOT npmlog@4.1.2 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^4.0.2
    58 silly placeDep ROOT rc@1.2.8 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^1.2.7
    59 silly placeDep node_modules/node-pre-gyp rimraf@2.7.1 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^2.6.1
    60 silly placeDep ROOT tar@4.4.13 OK for: node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 want: ^4
    61 silly fetch manifest debug@^3.2.6
    62 silly fetch manifest sax@^1.2.4
    63 silly fetch manifest abbrev@1
    64 silly fetch manifest osenv@^0.1.4
    65 silly fetch manifest ignore-walk@^3.0.1
    66 silly fetch manifest npm-bundled@^1.0.1
    67 silly fetch manifest npm-normalize-package-bin@^1.0.1
    68 silly fetch manifest are-we-there-yet@~1.1.2
    69 silly fetch manifest console-control-strings@~1.1.0
    70 silly fetch manifest gauge@~2.7.3
    71 silly fetch manifest deep-extend@^0.6.0
    72 silly fetch manifest ini@~1.3.0
    73 silly fetch manifest strip-json-comments@~2.0.1
    74 silly fetch manifest chownr@^1.1.1
    75 silly fetch manifest fs-minipass@^1.2.5
    76 silly fetch manifest minipass@^2.8.6
    77 silly fetch manifest minizlib@^1.2.1
    78 silly fetch manifest yallist@^3.0.3
    79 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sax 224ms (from cachex
    
    [ *** leaving out some success messages in order to save characters *** ]
    
    180 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi 12ms (from cache)
    181 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point 49ms (from cache)
    182 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align Completed in 53ms
    183 silly placeDep node_modules/gauge is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 OK for: string-width@1.0.2 want: ^1.0.0
    184 timing idealTree:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/string-width Completed in 2ms
    185 timing idealTree:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 0ms
    186 silly placeDep node_modules/gauge ansi-regex@2.1.1 OK for: strip-ansi@3.0.1 want: ^2.0.0
    187 timing idealTree:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 1ms
    188 timing idealTree:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 0ms
    189 timing idealTree:node_modules/libxmljs/node_modules/bindings Completed in 0ms
    190 timing idealTree:node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist Completed in 0ms
    191 timing idealTree:node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug Completed in 0ms
    192 timing idealTree:node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/rimraf Completed in 0ms
    193 timing idealTree:node_modules/tar/node_modules/yallist Completed in 0ms
    194 silly placeDep node_modules/wide-align is-fullwidth-code-point@2.0.0 OK for: string-width@2.1.1 want: ^2.0.0
    195 silly placeDep node_modules/wide-align strip-ansi@4.0.0 OK for: string-width@2.1.1 want: ^4.0.0
    196 silly fetch manifest ansi-regex@^3.0.0
    197 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex 45ms (from cache)
    198 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/string-width Completed in 50ms
    199 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 1ms
    200 silly placeDep node_modules/wide-align ansi-regex@3.0.0 OK for: strip-ansi@4.0.0 want: ^3.0.0
    201 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 1ms
    202 timing idealTree:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 0ms
    203 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 2000ms
    204 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 10ms
    205 timing idealTree Completed in 2971ms
    206 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 2972ms
    207 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 38ms
    208 silly reify moves {}
    209 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 1ms
    210 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 92ms
    211 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
    212 timing reifyNode:node_modules/osenv Completed in 634ms
    213 timing reifyNode:node_modules/libxmljs/node_modules/bindings Completed in 634ms
    214 timing reifyNode:node_modules/chownr Completed in 637ms
    215 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-minipass Completed in 643ms
    216 timing reifyNode:node_modules/os-tmpdir Completed in 644ms
    217 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ini Completed in 645ms
    218 timing reifyNode:node_modules/strip-json-comments Completed in 646ms
    219 timing reifyNode:node_modules/os-homedir Completed in 646ms
    220 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align Completed in 646ms
    221 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 647ms
    222 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 648ms
    223 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/string-width Completed in 649ms
    224 timing reifyNode:node_modules/aproba Completed in 648ms
    225 timing reifyNode:node_modules/has-unicode Completed in 649ms
    226 timing reifyNode:node_modules/wide-align/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 650ms
    227 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/ansi-regex Completed in 650ms
    228 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/strip-ansi Completed in 650ms
    229 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point Completed in 650ms
    230 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge/node_modules/string-width Completed in 650ms
    231 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ignore-walk Completed in 651ms
    232 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npm-bundled Completed in 652ms
    233 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npm-packlist Completed in 657ms
    234 timing reifyNode:node_modules/abbrev Completed in 666ms
    235 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minipass Completed in 672ms
    236 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minizlib Completed in 677ms
    237 timing reifyNode:node_modules/console-control-strings Completed in 676ms
    238 timing reifyNode:node_modules/minipass/node_modules/yallist Completed in 692ms
    239 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tar/node_modules/yallist Completed in 699ms
    240 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/rimraf Completed in 702ms
    241 timing reifyNode:node_modules/deep-extend Completed in 706ms
    242 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npmlog Completed in 710ms
    243 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sax Completed in 715ms
    244 timing reifyNode:node_modules/delegates Completed in 722ms
    245 timing reifyNode:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 740ms
    246 timing reifyNode:node_modules/nopt Completed in 742ms
    247 timing reifyNode:node_modules/are-we-there-yet Completed in 749ms
    248 timing reifyNode:node_modules/needle/node_modules/debug Completed in 760ms
    249 timing reifyNode:node_modules/rc Completed in 784ms
    250 timing reifyNode:node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin Completed in 811ms
    251 timing reifyNode:node_modules/gauge Completed in 854ms
    252 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 945ms
    253 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 950ms
    254 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:mem:SBdyJAz7PzbHtnwWkMO+rogAl51jICnD4nyzqW8VWXZWJt5UygkE+hg7jafoTcZ3u+l+9QEIT5wpevdBVQxijw== Completed in 54ms
    255 timing reifyNode:node_modules/tar Completed in 1004ms
    256 timing reifyNode:node_modules/node-pre-gyp Completed in 1063ms
    257 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mem 254ms (from cache)
    258 timing metavuln:packument:mem Completed in 257ms
    259 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:mem:1084 Completed in 1ms
    260 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:mem:1084 Completed in 259ms
    261 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:in-gfw:SoNlHLO6tYd1NL6s9kkKfueEz/rSuSeC0EQMpuTvqJCWERJOyfeEflb0GyQ/uHgWlRnwSbazwErmCZt7VnP+9A== Completed in 74ms
    262 timing reifyNode:node_modules/needle Completed in 1336ms
    263 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/in-gfw 434ms (from cache)
    264 timing metavuln:packument:in-gfw Completed in 445ms
    265 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:in-gfw:SBdyJAz7PzbHtnwWkMO+rogAl51jICnD4nyzqW8VWXZWJt5UygkE+hg7jafoTcZ3u+l+9QEIT5wpevdBVQxijw== Completed in 0ms
    266 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:in-gfw:SBdyJAz7PzbHtnwWkMO+rogAl51jICnD4nyzqW8VWXZWJt5UygkE+hg7jafoTcZ3u+l+9QEIT5wpevdBVQxijw== Completed in 451ms
    267 timing metavuln:cache:get:security-advisory:windows-build-tools:XFMS6BOvmzoGrDWvbiS89NGPqjCBKjs8hboRN+ZLu/m6coJ2tawHHOQyPxgKelmeVLIyyfR/9y6VC2/Z1DIzpg== Completed in 45ms
    268 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools 95ms (from cache)
    269 timing metavuln:packument:windows-build-tools Completed in 111ms
    270 timing metavuln:load:security-advisory:windows-build-tools:SoNlHLO6tYd1NL6s9kkKfueEz/rSuSeC0EQMpuTvqJCWERJOyfeEflb0GyQ/uHgWlRnwSbazwErmCZt7VnP+9A== Completed in 2ms
    271 timing metavuln:calculate:security-advisory:windows-build-tools:SoNlHLO6tYd1NL6s9kkKfueEz/rSuSeC0EQMpuTvqJCWERJOyfeEflb0GyQ/uHgWlRnwSbazwErmCZt7VnP+9A== Completed in 114ms
    272 timing auditReport:init Completed in 925ms
    273 timing reify:audit Completed in 1877ms
    274 timing reifyNode:node_modules/libxmljs Completed in 5256ms
    275 timing reify:unpack Completed in 5260ms
    276 timing reify:unretire Completed in 1ms
    277 timing build:queue Completed in 76ms
    278 timing build:link:node_modules/needle Completed in 63ms
    279 timing build:link:node_modules/detect-libc Completed in 65ms
    280 timing build:link:node_modules/node-pre-gyp Completed in 64ms
    281 timing build:link:node_modules/nopt Completed in 63ms
    282 timing build:link:node_modules/rc Completed in 66ms
    283 timing build:link:node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/rimraf Completed in 68ms
    284 timing build:link Completed in 70ms
    285 info run libxmljs@0.19.7 install node_modules/libxmljs node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http
    286 info run libxmljs@0.19.7 install { code: 1, signal: null }
    287 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 0ms
    288 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
    289 timing command:install Completed in 95471ms
    290 verbose stack Error: command failed
    290 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> \
        (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
    290 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
    290 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
    290 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit \
        (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
    291 verbose pkgid libxmljs@0.19.7
    292 verbose cwd C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY
    293 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    294 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" \
        "C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" \
        "i" "libxmljs"
    295 verbose node v15.5.0
    296 verbose npm  v7.0.10
    297 error code 1
    298 error path C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs
    299 error command failed
    300 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "node-pre-gyp install \
        --fallback-to-build --loglevel http"
    301 error Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine \
        parallele Erstellung zu ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "-m" hinzufügen.
    301 error   libxmljs.cc
    301 error   xml_attribute.cc
    301 error   xml_document.cc
    301 error   xml_element.cc
    301 error   xml_comment.cc
    301 error   xml_namespace.cc
    301 error   xml_node.cc
    301 error   xml_sax_parser.cc
    301 error C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\src\xml_sax_parser.cc(130,10): \
        warning C4996: 'Nan::MakeCallback': wurde als veraltet deklariert \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error   xml_syntax_error.cc
    301 error   xml_text.cc
    301 error   xml_pi.cc
    301 error   xml_xpath_context.cc
    301 error   buf.c
    301 error   catalog.c
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(984,19): warning \
        C4013: "open" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(1003,7): \
        warning C4013: "close" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\catalog.c(1010,15): \
        warning C4013: "read" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error   chvalid.c
    301 error   dict.c
    301 error   encoding.c
    301 error   entities.c
    301 error   error.c
    301 error   globals.c
    301 error   hash.c
    301 error   HTMLparser.c
    301 error   HTMLtree.c
    301 error   legacy.c
    301 error   list.c
    301 error   parser.c
    301 error   parserInternals.c
    301 error   pattern.c
    301 error   relaxng.c
    301 error   SAX2.c
    301 error   SAX.c
    301 error   tree.c
    301 error   threads.c
    301 error   uri.c
    301 error   valid.c
    301 error   xinclude.c
    301 error   xlink.c
    301 error   xmlIO.c
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(733,15): \
        warning C4013: "read" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(754,13): \
        warning C4013: "write" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(772,16): \
        warning C4013: "close" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(3743,19): \
        warning C4013: "getcwd" undefiniert; Annahme: extern mit Rückgabetyp int \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error \
        C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\vendor\libxml\xmlIO.c(3743,38): \
        warning C4047: "!=": Anzahl der Dereferenzierungen bei "int" und "void *" \
        unterschiedlich ?
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error   xmlmemory.c
    301 error   xmlmodule.c
    301 error   xmlreader.c
    301 error   xmlregexp.c
    301 error   xmlsave.c
    301 error   xmlschemas.c
    301 error   xmlschemastypes.c
    301 error   xmlstring.c
    301 error   xmlunicode.c
    301 error   xmlwriter.c
    301 error   xpath.c
    301 error   xpointer.c
    301 error   win_delay_load_hook.cc
    301 error LINK : fatal error LNK1194: Verzögertes Laden von "node.exe" aufgrund des \
        Imports des Datensymbols ""__declspec(dllimport) const \
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7Allocator@ArrayBuffer@v8@@6B@)" \
        nicht möglich. Link ohne /DELAYLOAD:node.exe \
        [C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    301 error Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe \
        C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build \
        --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http \
        --module=C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node \
        --module_name=xmljs \
        --module_path=C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release \
        --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 \
        --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
    302 error node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
    302 error node-pre-gyp http GET \
        https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v88-win32-x64.tar.gz
    302 error node-pre-gyp http 404 \
        https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v88-win32-x64.tar.gz
    302 error node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): \
        https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v88-win32-x64.tar.gz
    302 error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for libxmljs@0.19.7 and \
        node@15.5.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    302 error node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball \        
        https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.19.7/node-v88-win32-x64.tar.gz
    302 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    302 error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
    302 error gyp info using node@15.5.0 | win32 | x64
    302 error gyp info ok
    302 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/node-v15.5.0-headers.tar.gz
    302 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/node-v15.5.0-headers.tar.gz
    302 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    302 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-x86/node.lib
    302 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-arm64/node.lib
    302 error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-x64/node.lib
    302 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    302 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-x86/node.lib
    302 error gyp http 404 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-arm64/node.lib
    302 error gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.5.0/win-x64/node.lib
    302 error gyp ERR! build error
    302 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` \
        failed with exit code: 1
    302 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit \
        (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
    302 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
    302 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit \
        (node:internal/child_process:284:12)
    302 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    302 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" \
        "C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" \
        "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel=http" \
        "--module=C:\\usr\\dvl\\JavaScript\\YYYY\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release\\xmljs.node" \
        "--module_name=xmljs" \
        "--module_path=C:\\usr\\dvl\\JavaScript\\YYYY\\node_modules\\libxmljs\\build\\Release" \
        "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" \
        "--node_napi_label=node-v88"
    302 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs
    302 error gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.0
    302 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
    302 error gyp ERR! not ok
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute \
        'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe \
        C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js \
        build --fallback-to-build --loglevel=http \
        --module=C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node \
        --module_name=xmljs \
        --module_path=C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release \
        --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 \
        --node_napi_label=node-v88' (1)
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> \
        (C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:3A76:20)
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose \
        (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit \
        (node:internal/child_process:295:5)
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" \
        "C:\\usr\\dvl\\JavaScript\\YYYY\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" \
        "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel" "http"
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\usr\dvl\JavaScript\YYYY\node_modules\libxmljs
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.0
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
    302 error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    303 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: It’s trying and failing to build the native module from source and failing. This is a better question asked of the package maintainers. It might help here to post English error messages from the build...

Comment: @Joe: You're right, but I needed to change the machine settings completely, Actually, as you can see, there is just one fatal error on the second-to-last line numbered 301 which even outputs a linker error number. I suppose that this message leads directly to the problem, even if the message text is partially in German.
However, as you can see from my answer below, a found a satisfying solution to myself. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the libxmljs gyp build scripts for Windows are not maintained anymore. However, as I (Dr.Google, to be precise) found out, libxmljs2 and libxmljs2-xsd in combination appear to form a good replacement. Since I'm not able to compare to libxml.js, I cannot tell if libxmljs and libxmljs2 are equivalent. However, libxmljs2 does all what I need so far, e.g. schema validation.

Observation: Document.toString() always outputs "UTF-8" regardless of the encoding set. I don't know if the behavior is the same with libxmljs - I would expect the actual encoding to be output. This would make sense because I could convert an Xml string to a byte array using any encoding, so having "UTF-8" specified in the prolog would be misleading if I used latin-1, for example.